# Pass tkinter variable to another function

Tags: python, tkinter

I seem to have great difficulties understanding how functions pass information to one another.  Been teaching myself Python for a while now and I always hit a brick wall.

In the example below the *create_list()* function knows nothing about *playerlist* or the tkinter widget *playerOption*.  I really don't know how to overcome this problem!

All help very much appreciated.  It's been about 6 hours of work today and I've got nowhere!  Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *


def create_list(surname):

    table = r'c:\directory\players.dbf'

    with table:
        # Create an index of column/s
        index = table.create_index(lambda rec: (rec.name))

        # Creates a list of matching values
        matches = index.search(match=(surname,), partial=True)

        # Populate playerOption Menu with playerlist.
        playerlist = []
        for item in matches:
            playerlist.append([item[4], item[2], item[1]])

        m = playerOption.children['menu']
        m.delete(0, END)
        for line in playerlist:
            m.add_command(label=line,command=lambda v=var,l=line:v.set(l))


def main():

    master = Tk()
    master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400, 125))
    master.title('Assign a Player to a Team')

    entry = Entry(master, width = 50)
    entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5)

    def get_surname():

        surname = entry.get()

        create_list(surname)

    surname_button = Button(master, text='Go', command=get_surname)
    surname_button.grid(row = 0, column = 7, sticky = W)

    # Menu for player choosing.
    var = StringVar(master)

    playerlist = ['']
    playerOption = OptionMenu(master, var, *playerlist)
    playerOption.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 4, sticky = EW)

    mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`playlist` is local variable created in `main`. You have to create `global` variable to use it in another function.

```
# create global variable 

playlist = ['']
#playlist = None


def create_list(surname):
    # inform function `create_list` to use global variable `playlist`
    global playlist

    # assign empty list to global variable - not to create local variable
    # because there is `global playlist`
    playerlist = []

    for item in matches:
        # append element to global variable 
        # (it doesn't need `global playlist`)
        playerlist.append([item[4], item[2], item[1]])



def main():
    # inform function `main` to use global variable `playlist`
    global playlist


    # assign list [''] to global variable - not to create local variable
    # because there is `global playlist`
    playlist = ['']

    # use global variable 
    # (it doesn't need `global playlist`)
    playerOption = OptionMenu(master, var, *playerlist)
```

You can skip `global playlist` in function if you don't want assign new list to `playlist` in that function.

Comment: Thanks!  I was told to avoid global variables as much as possible though so I was trying not to do this.

Comment: @INoble: "Avoid global variables" is much too broad an advice.  Imports and defs create global names.  The advice should be "Don't use global variables to avoid passing objects to and returning objects from functions".  When writing gui callbacks, the framework determines the signatures, you you have to either use globals or a class to pass values between functions.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy that's some good advice I think.  I've been tearing my hair out trying to get rid of all the global variables and it just doesn't seem to make sense.  The perils of being self-taught I suppose!

Comment: @INoble: The advice is aimed as something like the following: `def sq(): global sqout; sqout=sqin*sqin \nsqin=3; sq(); print(sqout)`, which runs fine but is awful.  Do avoid things like that ;-).